# Why was my Visual Studio Code-related answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I don't know who can even see it, but I don't know why [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77159521/8285811) was deleted. If there's an issue with it, why can't someone just leave a comment explaining the issue?

In the answer, I give options that are not provided in other answers, show all the options available, and show the main differences of the option that seems to be the best. None of the other answers do this. Why would this be deleted while the other answers stay?

###### Copy of the answer below

> ---
>
> As mentioned in the top answer, so far the [**Tab Groups**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usama8800.tab-groups)
> extension is the best implementation I've found. Unlike the others,
> this one actually allow you to:
>
> - keep track of any split editors you already had open
> - view all the groups in a separate side bar window instead of at the bottom of the "Explorer"    [image: different side bar icon]
> - there are some bugs though
>
> ---
>
> The current options I've seen include:
>
> - Extension: [Tab Groups](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usama8800.tab-groups) (preferred)
> - Extension: [Tabstronaut](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jhhtaylor.tabstronaut&ssr=false#overview) (close second thanks to the functionality)
> - Extension: [Editor Group Minimizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=suhay.vscode-editor-group-minimizer&ssr=false#overview) (similar to "Tabstronaut")
> - Built-in: "[Editor Groups](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_editor-groups)"
> - Extension: [Tab Group](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jiapeiyao.tab-group) (basically the same as "Editor Groups")
>
> See and upvote the current [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/100335) for tab groups!

Comment: Seems to be an answer that merely says an exiting answer is correct. You add more *detail* but that's all.

Comment: it's a duplicate answer

Comment: I literally mentioned what is different in the second paragraph. Please point me to the answer that explains what is better about the first option as I described. Or which answer lists the other options available. Are you suggesting I should instead have modified someone's answer that focuses on one extension to include all these details?

Comment: There's only one link in your answer that isn't already included in another answer, and you don't even seem to recommend that one as a decent option. What value does this answer provide? it's more or less a summary of all existing answers. edit: 2 links, sorry. out of 6.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to promote an extension, you have multiple links, to the extension in your answer.  Even this question, proposes you are linking to a SO answer, but in reality, are linked to a Visual Studio extension. Furthermore, if all your answer does is confirm that an existing answer is valid, then what you have submitted is commentary.

Comment: There is obviously a benefit to someone knowing all the options available to them. There are plenty of very good answers like that across StackOverflow. And obviously not trying to promote an extension. That seems irrelevant.

Comment: I don't see a problem with providing an answer including the two that aren't already provided as answers...

Comment: @SecurityHound The text linking to the extension is a typo I'm pretty sure. It did originally link to their answer, but it changed when they added their answer's text to the question. I would change it back myself, but apparently I'm not cool enough.

Comment: Once again, my answer has many obvious benefits compared to the other answers. Especially showing the various options with their differences in a common format. I shouldn't have to look through 5 answers to form my opinion if there's a single answer comparing all the options.

Comment: That defeats the purpose of individual answers having separate scores.

Comment: @KevinB No it doesn't. There's a reason community wikis are a thing. So that we can have a comprehensive answer instead of a million ones including different details. They can both have their place. It doesn't have to be one or the other.

Comment: Why are you talking about Community Wiki posts as a defense when you never made yours one?

Comment: @TylerH What?... You can obviously understand the benefit of something without doing that thing? So, if I had made my post a community wiki, it suddenly would have changed the arguments?

Comment: @Akaisteph7 - No, I probably would flag your answer as “not an answer”, since I find answers which are flag posts for other answers, not to be helpful and not actually an answer. Upvoting the answer you found helpful would have been helpful

Comment: Please keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**. Weighing the merits of other answers is meta commentary, not a separate answer.

Comment: It was undeleted at 2024-01-12T19:18:40Z+0.

Comment: Did you not get a notification about the deletion? I noticed that it was deleted almost 4 months ago... It's definitely not a good idea to delete user content (that they put effort in) without any warnings.

Comment: @cuzy "Getting a notification" is a pretty vague term. Things which are sent by the site are often not received... because people don't look. For correct, frictionless interaction with the site people should keep an eye on their personal user control panel where you can't miss a thing. I'll give a personal example; when I was quite new to the site I decided to go look and noticed that quite a few of my recent flags were declined and so I learned I was doing it wrong. You have to go look and take an interest to know what's up. Waiting for the site to notify you is often already too late.

Comment: @Gimby I'm sorry for being vague, but I would simply have expected these kind of things to show up in the "Inbox (All)" regardless of whether I read it or not, similiar to how your comment gave me a notification that I can see in my Inbox. I know it is not going to change (soon), but I can see how it's confusing to have your content deleted without notice.

Comment: @Cuzy No I got no notification and didn't even know before this that I could find out whether some items of mine had been deleted. And I've been on the site for a while! This definitely made it more frustrating to me indeed. I would have gotten a notification if someone had simply left a comment though. Something as simple as the close reason auto leaving a comment could work.

Answer (score 16):

It's been a while, but if I recall correctly, I voted to delete this answer because it appears to largely repeat the existing answers. There's no need to create a separate answer that repeats solutions found and presented by other people. If you want to indicate to others that you think a particular answer is the best option, upvote it rather than posting another answer saying "the solution in answer X is the best answer".

Comment: I think the option I highlighted is the best because I compared it to other options. The benefit of the answer is to show all the options available and show what is different between them. I didn't reach that conclusion from the top answer, it just happened to match my conclusion. Either ways, none of this changes the fact that the content of the answer is very different. Are you saying there is no benefits in comparing different options available?

Comment: @Akaisteph7 - Comparing the different options, presented by other answers, as an answer isn’t helpful.

Comment: eh, i can think of some cases where comparing answers *could* be helpful as yet another answer, potentially as a wiki, this just isn't among them... it doesn't even compare them.

Comment: Well, regardless of all the arguments people seem to be giving in support of this decision, it seems the real reason my answer is "not good" is that it agrees with another previously-posted answer. Regardless of whatever extra information or different reasoning I can provide, you guys seem to think that agreeing with another answer means it IS the same answer. Kinda weird logic and there's PLENTY of examples against this on the sites but I guess most people here seem to agree with it this time.

Comment: i mean, i'd happily apply equal action against any other example that i can find. ;)

Comment: I wouldn't though as such answers are actually helpful. But it is good to at least know why this happened instead of deletions without an explanation. I don't see how that's supposed to help people understand how to "improve" their answers.

Comment: @Akaisteph7 It's not so black and white. Your answer _primarily/majority_ repeated content. If you had _just_ suggested another option that hadn't yet been suggested, and nothing else, it probably wouldn't have been deleted. Instead the first half of your answer is just "this other answer is the best answer and here's why I think so". The second half is a list of solutions which starts out by repeating that other answer's solution as well as at least one other solution that has already been provided as an answer. New answers should present _new_ solutions, not repeat existing ones.